# Chrome 63 seems to ignore or break on worker-src CSP headers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker, content-security-policy

#### The Error

I'm developing several apps that use web workers and all of them are kind of broken using the latest `Chrome V63.0.3230.132`.

This is the error message I see on the console:

> [Report Only] Refused to create a worker from 'http://localhost:8080/d04af186322390d53036.worker.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "worker-src 'none'".

I've also noticed [some other sites](https://web-perf.github.io/react-worker-dom/test/dbmonster/index.html#count=1&timeout=0&worker=true&rows=50) behaving the same way.

Apparently, it doesn't matter how one creates that worker.
I tried it in a react app using [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader), but also in a plain JS demo where I created it manually. The error remains the same.

#### What I tried

I've got all the CSP headers in place, and also updated my `manifest.json` files with [the correct CSP entry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) to no avail.

All other browsers are working fine.

Can someone confirm or explain this behavior?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Upd**: in this case the issue was root-caused to having uMatrix plugin installed and enabled. Even when the plugin switched off the issue did remain. So there are two ways to workaround those confusing errors:

- Disable uMatrix completely in the Extension/Plugins menu in the browser. Using a built in "turn off" button in uMatrix will not help.
- Just let it go and ignore the warning.

The details are here https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix/issues/926#issuecomment-359905357

---

**Initial reply for history.**

**Xceno**, did you confirm that Chrome really fails to load the worker?

I see the exact same error, but... the SW actually works. Maybe this is just a false-positive bug from Chrome.

Here is my code and what I see in console

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    // ... some other code
}
```

Console output:

```
defer.js:36 [Report Only] Refused to create a worker from 'https://.../sw.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "worker-src 'none'".
defer.js:37 ServiceWorker registration successful with scope:  https://.../
```

In my case SW was in fact successfully installed and worked as designed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! Well, it's actually a bit weird for me. Sometimes it loads, sometimes just nothing happens (with no other error than "refused to load...").
I have since downgraded `worker-loader` for Webpack to an earlier version which seems to work most of the time. But it's still not perfect.

What also strikes me, is that Chrome seems to ignore all settings regarding `worker-src`. Did you try setting CSP headers too?

Comment: No I did not. I'm almost certain I'm not setting anything _specific_ in headers but I'll check and dump my headers here if that helps.

To add to that — Firefox is not reporting anything like that to me.

PS
And BTW I was having a lot of unexpected behaviors with Service Workers until I made it a habit to close all the tabs in case I'm changing a worker code.

Comment: Here are the headers

Answer (score 1):

As promised — here are the headers. I was unable to put them as a comment. As you can see I don't have CSP headers explicitly and the only one related to security are `x-content-type-options` and `x-frame-options`. That's it. Hope it helps somehow.

```
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
cache-control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
content-language: en
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
vary: Accept-Encoding
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 3e91b05aabb05540-ORD
content-encoding: br
x-firefox-spdy: h2
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out ASAP and report back!

Comment: Any news here? In my case the following has changed _All other browsers are working fine_. Now Firefox 58 and Chrome 64 are behaving similarly. As soon as `navigator.serviceWorker.register` is called, both browsers complain about `worker-src 'none'` CPS. Firefox is more verbose though. It also drops the following (translated into English by me) `Content Security Policy: report URI (about:blank) must be HTTP or HTTPS URI`. I'm puzzled.

Comment: And still. a service worker successfully installs and works like no error was found. BTW, in my case a SW is being registered from a JS file, not from an inline script. I have just tried inlining it, but the result was the same.

Comment: Meanwhile, I've upgraded FF and Chrome and confirm what you're saying. The browsers still complain and chrome completely ignores my CSP headers _but_ the web workers load regardless. I've got the feeling that the failed load attempts I've seen are more of a webpack issue. I'm going to accept your answer, but I'm still curious about the ignored CSP headers. Thanks for all your effort!

Comment: I have a better answer for you. Confirmed. I'm almost certain you have uMatrix installed. Try disabling it and repeat your test. It worked for me showing no more errors in the console (both browsers). If you confirm, then I'll go ahead and try editing the answer you have accepted.

Comment: Ha, holy crap that was it. I've got `uMatrix` and `ghostery` in every browser on all my machines. Never thought about those... Thanks again, lessons learned!